# Pi as WiFi Repeater

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

There are many blog posts about using a Pi as an Access Point.
But all the posts I read assumed the internet coming from Ethernet.

As anyone successfully used the Pi as Wi-Fi Repeater?
Other than that one of the Wifi USB adapter should be AP compatible and Linux support, is there anything in particular to watch out for the two USB WiFi adapters?

Comment: Add "network bridge" with your raspberry pi search.

Comment: you'd be much better off using a cheaper dedicated hardware like [this one](http://www.amazon.com/TP-LINK-TL-MR3020-Wireless-Portable-Router/dp/B00634PLTW) instead of spending your time trying to customize your Pi with the inferior results.

Comment: @lenik I'd also like to use the Pi to store files and as a media center. All that wirelessly. So I may as well just buy a second WiFi USB adapter. With inferior results do you mean in terms of reliability or throughput/reach?

Comment: @brillout.com Don't be discouraged by the naysayers. We bought the Raspberry Pi knowing the risks involved configuring it to our liking. At least we're able to tweak settings where as many routers you're at their mercy of their limited web interface. In fact I got better results with the RPi2 than any other router I've purchased. I'm also working on a WiFi repeater so I may post back here eventually. P.S. As long as you buy high gain antennas/adapter backed with a powered USB hub you should be fine.

Comment: Also, it looks like it has been done before: http://www.ce3c.be/256-using-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-repeater/